# Why does assignment not always work in Angular expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just found this interesting apparent inconsistency in what is allowed in Angular expressions:

1. It is possible to perform assignment in an expression
2. This breaks if the assignment involves a local variable from an ngRepeat
3. This can be overcome by using a setter defined in the controller instead of assignment in the expression

[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lt57nqfm3TH7XdFa5xML?p=preview)

The [docs on expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) seem only to explicitly disallow control flow in expressions, and I don't see any mention of the kind of behavior above.

I suppose the takeaway from this is it's probably a better design pattern to use a setter anyway, but does anyone know of a more definitive reference on what's possible in expressions?

Maybe it would be better if Angular unilaterally prohibited assignment in them. (A related inconsistency is that it seems to be possible to increment in an expression with i = i+1 but not with i+=1...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a known problem with scoping in directives. You can read the article [The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance) to know more about the `scoping` in angular js.

Any primitive value assignment from a child/transcluded scope will create a new instance value instead of changing the parent scopes value

In your case you are working with a primitive value `selectedNumber`.

There are two suggested ways to fix it

Solution 1 
*Use a object instead of primitive value.*

1. Change selectedNumber  to an object `scope.selectedNumber = { num : 1 };`
2. Change display to `<h2>{{ selectedNumber.num }}</h2>`
3. Change the click handler in `ng-repeat` to `ng-click="selectedNumber.num = number"`

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TxPD9lKFI9T4S5uZ4i07?p=preview)

Solution 2:
*Use `$parent` scope reference*

1. Change the click handler in `ng-repeat` to `ng-click="$parent.selectedNumber = number"`

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e6ncIbHiKRz6rX94XlXh?p=preview)

Solution 3:
*Use a setter in the parent scope*

1. Create a setter method in the parent scope like `$scope.setSelectedNumber = function(num){ $scope.selectedNumber = num}`
2. Change the click event to `setSelectedNumber(number)`
   (This is the method already used)

*Update:* 

As suggested by Anders Ekdahl, it is advisable to use the object (solution 1) based solution.

Comment: You should be using an object as the model instead of accessing the parent scope by $parent. Accessing $parent leads to brittle code, since it will stop working if you were to add another scope in between.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl you are right, I just gave the available options as the answer, the pointer article explains the use cases and the problems

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick answer! That makes complete sense. FYI, the real use-case for this is dynamically selecting the page background in a page editor based on an array of preview "swatches". The value being set is called 'selectedClass', but it is a string, so I guess it's still a primitive type and the same issue applies. Though it's awesome to see your solutions, do you think a setter in the controller would be a better design?