# AngularJS + Bootstrap Dropdown : can't do ng-click in ng-repeat

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a picker with Bootstrap Dropdown and AngularJS.

http://jsfiddle.net/qbjfQ/

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list"><a ng-click="current = item">Dynamic set {{item}}</a></li>
```

When I use ng-click statically in the list, it works fine (example 4 and 5)
But when I use ng-click in ng-repeat, it won't update the value (example 1 to 3)

What can I do ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a known problem with scoping in directives. You can read the article [The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance) to learn more about the scoping in angular js.

You need to change the `ng-repeat` to

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list">
  <a ng-click="$parent.current = item">
    Dynamic set {{item}}
  </a>
</li>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qbjfQ/1/)

For explanation of the problem, you can read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037743/why-does-assignment-not-always-work-in-angular-expressions/15037878#15037878) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037743/why-does-assignment-not-always-work-in-angular-expressions)

Comment: Or use the guideline: all scope references should contain a . (dot)  <a ng-click='current.thing = item'>

Comment: The original fiddle rotted (because the angular-ui library path changed).  Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbjfQ/288/).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a setter function within `ng-click`

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list"><a ng-click="setCurrent( item)">Dynamic set {{item}}</a></li>
```

JS

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.list = [1,2,3];
    $scope.setCurrent=function(val){
         $scope.current =val;
    }    
    $scope.current = 0;    
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qbjfQ/2/

Answer (score 1):

There's an angularjs directive that does exactly that: https://gist.github.com/andyvr/5205764

Here's the jsfiddle with examples: http://jsfiddle.net/M32pj/1/

```
Sample: 
<select ng-model="example1" bs-selectbox>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this but how do I reload the directive. My options come from a remote source.

Comment: Please upgrade your source code in ordre to $compile your template. It doesn't work with AngularJS 1.2+.
Thanks.